# Finding $f'(x)$ if $x\neq 0$ using definition of derivative

Tags: calculus

> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3 \sin (1/x),\quad x > 0 \\  x \sin x, \quad x\leq 0 \end{cases} $$

I'm not sure if I am doing this right but I applied the definition of derivative on $x^3 \sin (1/x)$ if $x>0$. but due to the $h$'s that I am getting, I am really confused. and my $h$'s aren't cancelling.

Comment: Post your work ....

Comment: lim where h->0 [(x+h)^3sin(1/x+h) - x^3sin(1/x)] / h
I expanded (x+h)^3 [which i think was really bad cause it introduce so many more algebraic term. and then i got lost.

Comment: @Yerin  It would be better to post your work within the body of the question.  Otherwise, users of this site might miss it.

Answer (score 1):

Just recall the definition of the derivative

$$ f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-0}{x-0}. $$

For the above limit to exist you need to prove the right and left limits are equal. For the right one we will have

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{x^3\sin(1/x)-0}{x-0}=\dots\,. $$

Try to finish the problem